Google Sheets Query referencing a Dropdown selection
I am attempting to create a sheet that populates data based upon a drop down menu. The data is coming from a Google form and has the following headers:
Timestamp
Decoding John
Decoding Anna
Decoding Vicky
Decoding Brad
Encoding John
Encoding Anna
Encoding Vicky
Encoding Brad
Write a dictated sentence John
Write a dictated sentence Anna
Write a dictated sentence Vicky
Write a dictated sentence Brad
What I am trying to do is have a drop down that has these names as options. When a name is selected, the main page populates all data that is in the columns with the corresponding name and the time stamp.
I've tried several different methods of doing this but they've all failed. Can someone assist with this?
Here is the copy of the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GdF9-iMhiDA3AiL4CkqRM8ByWEawTS0fVh85DNo9Qbw/edit?usp=sharing
I've tried using QUERY and IF statements but I'm not sure what to actually use. The Query option sounds like the correct one but I can't reference the drop down since they're on separate sheets.

Is it possible that you could elaborate on the expected outcome? I looked at your example sheet and I can't tell what you're after.

The answer provided below gave me the desired outcome (see the screenshots he added). I'm parsing through the formula to try and learn what they did (still relatively new to more advanced formulas) but looks like it worked.


Here's one approach you may test out:
=let(Λ,'Form Responses 1'!A2:M, Σ,offset(Λ,-1,,1),
 choosecols(Λ,1,xmatch(B4&"  ["&A2&"]",Σ),xmatch(C4&"  ["&A2&"]",Σ),xmatch("*sentence  ["&A2&"]",Σ,2)))


Explanation:

'Form Responses 1'!A2:M is assigned an identifier Λ via let
function
offset(Λ,-1,,1) translates to 'Form Responses 1'!A1:M1 & is also
assigned another identifier
the whole choosecols() part loosely translates to choosecols('Form Responses 1'!A2:M,1,8,4,12) for Vicky
xmatch(B4&"  ["&A2&"]",Σ) translates to xmatch("Encoding  [Vicky]",'Form Responses 1'!A1:M1) which outputs 8 since it is found at the 8th spot in the header; the same goes for other 2 xmatches as well. finally choosecols() arranges them all as one output


Thanks. This works but I'm having trouble parsing through it (I'm still new to more advanced formulas in Sheets). What exactly is going on here?

Glad they could solve it. I used to think I was good at Google sheets formulas until I started reviewing @rockinfreakshow's answers.

Added some basic explanation part to the answer section. Look into those specific formula documentations to get a more clear picture. @Kreeszh If interested to solve more wide variety of formula stuff, may I recommend checking out reddit sheets community and google docs community. I am over there as well...

@rockinfreakshow Thanks for the explination. Is there a way to add several ranges from other tabs to this? I tried using =let(Λ,{'Form Responses 1'!A2:M,'Form Responses 3'!A2:M}, Σ, offset(Λ,-1,,1),choosecols(Λ,1,xmatch(B4&"  ["&A2&"]",Σ),xmatch(C4&"  ["&A2&"]",Σ),xmatch("*sentence  ["&A2&"]",Σ,2))) but I'm getting a Value error "Function CHOOSECOLS parameter 3 expects number values, but got error."

Please check the YEUDOI sheet file, or look at this formula:

=ArrayFormula(QUERY('Form Responses 1'!A2:M,"Select Col1, "&"Col"&TEXTJOIN(",Col",1,MATCH(IF(B2:D2="Dictate Sentance","*sentence",B2:D2)&"  ["&A1&"]",'Form Responses 1'!A1:M1,0))&"  ",0))


Thanks. Is there a way to combine multiple tabs from this sheet using this method?

I think there is a method to use for multiple sheets; however, you need to share the file with an example
